# opencv: getting a sequence of images piped from gphoto2

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to get the output of gphoto2 movie capture over to my opencv program over a pipe

```
gphoto2 --capture-movie --stdin | ./myexe
```

My first attempt was to do it like this:

```
while(1)
{
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss <<  "/dev/stdin"; 
  cv::Mat m = cv::imread(ss.str());
  namedWindow( "LiveView", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow( "LiveView", m );                 
  waitKey(1);
}
```

But sadly, while compiling works, executing doesn't, I am getting an

```
OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.2+dfsg/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 2482 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.2+dfsg/modules/core/src/array.cpp:2482: error: (-206) Unrecognized or unsupported array type in function cvGetMat
```

I saw something similar asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899511/opencv-load-image-video-from-stdin), but it doesn't work for me - compiling fails at

```
readbytes=read(fileno(stdin),ca,BUFSIZE);
error: no matching function for call to ‘read(int, char [10240], int)’
```

I'm quite a novice to c++/opencv, so I'm probably missing some includes or something. 
Because I'm a new user, I cannot comment to ask for help/clarification over there, so I decided to ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 0):

This piping seems to be bad coding practice. Use the libgphoto API to extract the images/movie and use that with your OpenCV stuff.
It's easier than it sounds. See this blogpost: http://sepharads.blogspot.nl/2011/11/camera-tethered-capturing-using.html